# Disaggregate to minutes from a specific time interval sum in R

Tags: r, interpolation, aggregation

I need to do an hourly time aggregation of my data but first want to split it up into minutes. My data looks like this:

```
# Data set:
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", text="
time, counts, counts_sec
2016-07-29 13:24:00, 10, 38
2016-07-29 13:44:00, 254, 1200
2016-07-29 14:04:00, 287, 1200
2016-07-29 14:24:00, 301, 1200")
dd$time <- as.POSIXct(dd$time)
```

The counts represent a cumulative sum of the counts_sec (10 counts in 38 seconds). Usually the measurement period was 20 minutes (1200 sec). I want now minute values and as a next step aggregate this values to an hourly sum.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: You want to get min values as [24,44,04,24...]?

Comment: The `xts` package and for example its function `to.period` can be useful for such tasks. Note though that "It is not possible to convert a series from a lower periodicity to a higher periodicity - e.g. weekly to daily or daily to 5 minute bars, as that would require magic." (from `?to.period`). Try `dd_xts <- xts(dd$counts, order.by = dd$time)`; `dd_xts <- to.hourly(dd_xts)[, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to go back to a minute level when you have a 20min point of view, because you don't know exactly what happened within each minute.

However, you can get an hour point of view. I've some more observations to make more clear how the process works.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


dd <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", text="
time, counts, counts_sec
2016-07-29 13:24:00, 10, 38
2016-07-29 13:44:00, 254, 1200
2016-07-29 14:04:00, 287, 1200
2016-07-29 14:24:00, 301, 1200
2016-07-29 14:44:00, 254, 1200
2016-07-29 15:04:00, 287, 1200
2016-07-29 15:24:00, 301, 1200")

dd$time <- as.POSIXct(dd$time)

dd

#                  time counts counts_sec
# 1 2016-07-29 13:24:00     10         38
# 2 2016-07-29 13:44:00    254       1200
# 3 2016-07-29 14:04:00    287       1200
# 4 2016-07-29 14:24:00    301       1200
# 5 2016-07-29 14:44:00    254       1200
# 6 2016-07-29 15:04:00    287       1200
# 7 2016-07-29 15:24:00    301       1200


dd %>% 
  mutate(hour_range = 1+floor(as.numeric(difftime(time, min(time), units="hours")))) %>%   # calculate in which hour range you are based on the start time point
  group_by(hour_range) %>%                        # for each hour range
  summarise(start = min(time),                    # get the start time point
            sum_counts = sum(counts))             # get the sume of counts

# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   hour_range               start sum_counts
#        <dbl>              <dttm>      <int>
# 1          1 2016-07-29 13:24:00        551
# 2          2 2016-07-29 14:24:00        842
# 3          3 2016-07-29 15:24:00        301
```